# C language or programminng

Tags: c

Can someone help me print out the following characters:

```
* ********
** *******
*** ******
**** *****
***** ****
****** ***
******* **
******** *
```

That's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int row;
    int column;
    // fig a :
    for (row=1;row<=7;row++) {
        for  (column=1;column<=row;column++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not printing the upper right part. Change the for loops like this so that you print `*` for the remaining number if you subtract `row` from `7`

```
for (row = 1; row <= 7; row++) {
    for (column = 1; column <= row; column++)
        putchar('*');

    putchar(' ');
    for (column = row; column <= 7; column++)
        putchar('*');

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're only printing the bottom half of the set of characters.  You need to keep going until you hit the end of the row.

All rows are printing the same number of characters.  The only difference is where the space character is.  So on each row, always print `column` characters.  If it's time to print a space, print it, otherwise print a `*`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just printing the low corner right? that's cause you're printing `*` until `column = row` and then jump to the next line. You should be doing

```
for(row=1;row<=7;row++){
    for(column=1;column<=7;column++){
        printf("%c", column==row+1 ? ' ' : '*'); // If row==column print ' ' else '*'
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: the space should be where `column == row + 1`.

Comment: To get the result OP expects use `row<=9` and `column<=10`. `column == row` is fine with these limits.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate until `column<=row`, every row in your pattern has a constant width, you just need to know when to print the space - in your case it is the n + 1 position of the row where n is the number of the row. A working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int row=1;row<=7;row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= 10; column++) {
            if (column != row + 1)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can use C-style string for this task. A simple example -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     char a[11];                          // declare a char array
     for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
     { 
         memset(a,'*',(sizeof a) -1);     // initialize it with all elements as '*'
         a[i+1]=' ';                      // set particular index as ' '
         printf("%s\n",a);                // print string 
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

[output here.](https://ideone.com/AdyUwz)